# How to fix Incompatible types Required: java.lang.Throwable Found: org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericEntityException;?

Tags: java

I wrote a code which was working fine from months and suddenly started giving incompatible errors. This code is being used to create a new permission scheme in jira.

```
try{  
    permissionSchemeManager.createSchemeEntity(gv,schemeEntity);                    
} catch (GenericEntityException gex) {
    gex.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: We'll need a lot more context.

Comment: @shmosel updated question

Comment: That's a *little* more context. We don't know what classes you're referencing, what methods you're calling, what you're trying to do, or what recent change triggered this problem. As long as you hold that info to yourself, the best we can offer is our sympathy. Please see how to post a [mcve].